# Run MATLAB executable form Python: Could not find the version 9.1 of matlab runtime

Tags: python, windows, matlab, parameters, executable

I had a script written by a coworker in Python 2. I made some changes to convert it to Python 3 (not sure made right corrections). I have commented out parts with Python 2 code.
The issue is that script runs but then can't find the version of Matlab Runtime.
I have seen similar questions but answers are not clear.

this is what I get: **Couldn't find the version 9.1 of Matlab Runtime. Attempting to load mclmcrrt9_1.dll...**

```
def run_subprocess(process_name, arguments):
"""
:param process_name:
:type process_name: Pathlib2.Path()
:param arguments:
:type arguments: list
"""
# process_name = process_name.parent.joinpath(process_name.name + '.exe')     # Python 2
process_name = process_name.parent.joinpath(process_name.name)
command = [str(process_name)]
for item in arguments:
    command.append(item)

# sys.stderr.write(unicode(str(command) + u'\n').encode(cfg.encoding, 'replace'))   # Python 2
sys.stderr.write((str(command) + u'\n'))
output = ''
error = ''
try:
    my_process = psutil.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(my_process)
except Exception as e:
    # sys.stderr.write(unicode(str(e) + u'\n').encode(cfg.encoding, 'replace'))   # Python 2
    sys.stderr.write((str(e) + u'\n'))
    return '', 'Exception encountered with psutil.Popen(' + str(command) + ')'

try:
    output, error = my_process.communicate()
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write(unicode(str(e) + u'\n').encode(cfg.encoding, 'replace'))
    return '', 'Exception encountered with psutil.Popen(' + str(command) + ')'
# sys.stdout.write(unicode(output + u'\n').encode(cfg.encoding, 'replace'))  # Python 2
sys.stdout.write(output)
# sys.stderr.write(unicode(error + u'\n').encode(cfg.encoding, 'replace'))   # Python 2
sys.stderr.write(output)
return output, error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pymatlab](https://pypi.org/project/pymatlab/) package.

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pymatlab/wiki/Examples/) are some examples on how to use it.